# Why does my Fancybox window open and close immediately?

Tags: html, jquery, fancybox-3, barbajs

i am using barba js, i am listing image normally with php. But when I click on the fancy box, the Fancybox window opens and closes again.

[fancybox](https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/)

list

```
<a href="http://localhost/upload/pages/home/home_3894.png" data-fancybox="images" data-caption="aaa">
    <img class="product-image main-image" src="http://localhost/upload/pages/home/home_3894.png" data-image-id="64>
</a>

<a href="http://localhost/upload/pages/about/about_3895.png" data-fancybox="images" data-caption="aaa">
    <img class="product-image main-image" src="http://localhost/upload/pages/about/about_3895.png" data-image-id="66>
</a>
```

```
jQuery('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
        backFocus: false,
        buttons: [
            "zoom",
            "share",
            "slideShow",
            "fullScreen",
            "download",
            "thumbs",
            "close"
        ],
        thumbs: {
            autoStart: true,
        },
    });
```

Comment: It sounds very strange. Can you elaborate, or create a snippet?  I tried it and it works

Comment: problem barba js plugin fixed the issue.

Comment: Are you saying that you no longer need help? If so, please delete your question.

Comment: no problem not solved barba js question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it this way.
**data-barba-prevent**

```
<a href="..." data-barba-prevent><img></a>
```